# getting exception during getting session

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
please suggest what i'll do..actually i'm using facebook java api and i'm getting some xml response with error code 100 

**my code is :**
```

This is some part of code of my project please look into this and tell where i'm getting this problem...In this my login part is ok and getting post status 200 is ok and when i'm trying to get sessionid it gives error code 100 or invalid parameter ...

```
              PostMethod post = new PostMethod("/login.php?login_attempt=1");
              post.addParameter("api_key", API_KEY);
              post.addParameter("v", "1.0");
              post.addParameter("auth_token", token);
              post.addParameter("email",user_Name);
              post.addParameter("pass",password);
              int postStatus=0;
              try{
                      postStatus = http.executeMethod(post);
                 }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
              logger.info(" Exception Occur Here: "+e);
                }
              logger.info("LOGIN - Http status returned when executing POST: "+postStatus);
              if(postStatus >=200 ){login=true;}
              String sessionId="";
              try{
                      sessionId = client.auth_getSession(token);
                  if(sessionId!=null)
                      {
                       login=true;       
                      }
                      logger.info("Session key is " + sessionId+"---MSISDN---"+msisdn);
              }
            catch(Exception e)
              {
                 logger.fatal(e);              ***// here i'm getting exception***
              }

**and getting response is :**

<error_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
  <error_code>100</error_code>
  <error_msg>Invalid parameter</error_msg>
  <request_args list="true">
    <arg>
      <key>api_key</key>
      <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>auth_token</key>
      <value>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>call_id</key>
      <value>1322582630845</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>format</key>
      <value>xml</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>method</key>
      <value>facebook.auth.getSession</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>sig</key>
      <value>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</value>
    </arg>
    <arg>
      <key>v</key>
      <value>1.0</value>
    </arg>
  </request_args>
</error_response>

11-29@21:33:57,0902  INFO FacebookLogin:203 -  Second Exception Occur Here: com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException: Invalid parameter
11-29@21:33:57,0903 FATAL FacebookLogin:204 - com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException: Invalid parameter

**PLeaser solve my problem **
```

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.getSession/

getSession() takes the parameters: auth_token, callback, generate_session_secret, host_url

It appears that you're only passing auth_token.

Answer (score 0):

@user1060125

I am also using Facebook-Google API from long time. I too usually face the same problem.

This thing

> > facebook rest api java ERROR in taking session ID: com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException: Invalid parameter

Only happen when the Application, whose API Key and Secret Key you are using is not permitted by user, in other word you Facebook application has not Permission to access user.

I make user-ID be the app member by two way
One- By clicking following following canvas link

> https://apps.facebook.com/fbtocrbt

Or by using Apache  HTML library to automate the user authentication process by accessing following link.

> http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=APP_API-KEY&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream

and follow the resulting pages to authenticate user.

Hi, @Lynn Crumbling, as I know that google-facebook API use REST-Based Facebook API, but problem is that your link has no guide and disabled.

I have to start with Facebook RESTing then what I have to do? I request for a step by step guide if possible.